# Find question text block in image with Python Opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

How can I select question blocks in a jpg file with questions in Python code? The codes below select texts. I want to select question blocks with their choices.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('test2.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (9,9), 0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,30)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9,9))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=4)

cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts\[0\] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts\[1\]

ROI_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 10000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 3)
        ROI = image\[y:y+h, x:x+w\]
        cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
        ROI_number += 1

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Desired result:

[image]

I drew the rectangles in the picture with the mouse. There are no rectangles in the original picture.

The original file is here:

[image]

Comment: Can you add your original sample image without the drawn rectangles?

Comment: The original file is here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vpnaqjHvm8iKldi8lmjuVS4T3rf_Dm6G

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple approach is to obtain a binary image and perform [morphological operations](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html)
 to connect the text into a single contour. Here's the result:

Binary image

[image]

Dilate to connect contours

[image]

Result

[image]

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Morph operations
opening_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, opening_kernel, iterations=1)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (10,50))
dilate = cv2.dilate(opening, kernel, iterations=2)

# Remove center line
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ar = w / float(h)
    if area > 10000 and area < 12500 and ar < .5:
        cv2.drawContours(dilate, [c], -1, 0, -1)

# Dilate more
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (10,10))
dilate = cv2.dilate(dilate, kernel, iterations=3)

# Draw boxes
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 100000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 3)

cv2.imwrite('thresh.png', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('dilate.png', dilate)
cv2.imwrite('opening.png', opening)
cv2.imwrite('image.png', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 2):

There can be better solutions but here is my approach:

1. Make [erosion operation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaeb1e0c1033e3f6b891a25d0511362aeb) to image to be able to visible of paragraphs as just one contour.
2. Eliminate the middle line by doing it white.
3. Make erosion again after eliminating middle line.
4. Then your paragraphs will seem as one contour. Apply [minAreaRect](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minarearect).
5. Draw rectangles to source image.

***Note***: I coded in C++ because my environment based on C++ and I am not familiar with Python but it should be simple to convert.

Here is the code and result images:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <vector>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat img = imread("/ur/source/image/orijinal.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    resize(img,img,Size(img.cols/4,img.rows/4));

    Mat org = img.clone();
    Mat element = getStructuringElement( MORPH_ELLIPSE,
                                         Size( 2*10 + 1, 2*10+1 ),
                                         Point( 5, 5 ) );

    Mat dst;
    erode( img, dst, element );

    for(int i=0;i<dst.rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<dst.cols;j++)
        {
           if(dst.at<uchar>(Point(j,i))<252 && dst.at<uchar>(Point(j,i)) > 50 )
               dst.at<uchar>(Point(j,i)) = 255;
        }
    }

    Mat element2 = getStructuringElement( MORPH_ELLIPSE,
                                         Size( 2*10 + 1, 2*10+1 ),
                                         Point( 5, 5 ) );

    Mat dst2,threshold_output;
    erode( dst, dst2, element2);

        vector<vector<Point> > contours;
        vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

        /// Detect edges using Threshold
        threshold( dst2, threshold_output, 100, 255, THRESH_BINARY );
        /// Find contours
        findContours( threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

        /// Find the rotated rectangles for each contour
        vector<RotatedRect> minRect( contours.size() );

        for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
            minRect[i] = minAreaRect( Mat(contours[i]) );

        /// Draw contours + rotated rects
        Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );
        Mat result_zero = Mat::zeros( threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );

        for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
        {
            Scalar color(0,255,255);
            // detect contours
            drawContours( drawing, contours, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );

            Point2f rect_points[4]; minRect[i].points( rect_points );        
            for( int j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
            {        
                line( img, rect_points[j], rect_points[(j+1)%4], color, 1, 8 );
            }    
        }


    imshow("Source",org);

    imshow("Output1",dst);

    imshow("Output2",dst2);

    imshow("Output3",img);


    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Source:

[image]

First erosion:

[image]

Eliminate middle line and erosion again:

[image]

After minAreaRect draw rectangles to source image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest, Mr. Yunus. A nice approach. Let me try to adapt this method to python.